# Xcode 9 - "file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)"

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, build

I'm making an app for hobby purposes that uses the OpenCV library. I made a separate Xcode project in C++ that works successfully on its own, but when I tried adding the same OpenCV files from that project to my Swift project, on build it gave me this warning:

ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/whateverfilename.dylib,  file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /usr/local/Cellar/whateverfilename.dylib

repeated a whole bunch of times for all the files I had linked to.

I looked at other stack overflow questions and followed all the advice they gave, including adding i386 and x86_64 to my Valid Architectures, changing Build Active Architecture Only to No, and deleting my derived data, but nothing seems to work.

I'm sort of new to Xcode, is there anything terribly wrong with what I'm doing?

Additional semi-relevant info:

- My plan was to write all the OpenCV stuff in C++ and wrap it in obj-C so that Swift could use it.
- The iOS target is set to 10.3 because I'm testing the app on an old Ipad.
- I'm using Tesseract along with OpenCV
- I installed OpenCV using cmake

Comment: If you are building iOS apps, you need to rebuild opencv for Arm architecture. You can also download the prebuilt framework on OpenCV website, but it doesn’t contain opencv-contrib module.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could go about doing that?

Comment: Never mind I ended up using the TesseractOCRiOS cocoa pod which worked fine.